# Trouble With Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I've started tinkering with Mockito today and have had quite the struggle and was hoping somebody could straighten me out.

Basically all I want to do is be able to verify that the 3 methods in my getName() method are called.

For some reason though in my test, whenever I hit this line:

```
Mockito.verify(mock).getPathObj();
```

I end up getting this error:
***"Wanted but not invoked:
  mock.getPathObj();"***

**Here is the class I wanna test**

```
public class JavaFileInput {

private Path path;

public JavaFileInput(){
    super();
    this.path = null;
}

public Path getPathObj() {
    return this.path;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    Path path = getPathObj(); //<--I realize I could just use my path member var here.  Added for troubleshooting.
    return path.getFileName().toString();
}
}
```

**Here is my testing class**

```
public class TestJavaFileInput {

@Mock(name = "path") private Path path;
@InjectMocks private JavaFileInput mock = Mockito.mock(JavaFileInput.class);

@Before
public void testSetup(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void getNameTest(){
    mock.getName();
    Mockito.verify(mock).getName();
    Mockito.verify(mock).getPathObj();
}
}
```

Does anybody have some insight for me?

I have exhausted these resources, but I guess I could be easily overlooking something:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html
http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#21

Comment: You're not testing a real JavaFileInput instance. You're testing a mock of JavaFileInput. That makes no sense. By definition, methods of mock objects don't do anything other than what you tell them to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be mocking the class that you want to test.  Only mock external dependencies that you need.

Second, you need to specify behavior as to when that method is invoked.  What should your `Path` instance return?  This is where the mock comes in, as you need to decide what to return when `getFileName()` is invoked.

```
when(path.getFileName()).thenReturn(Paths.get("file://some/uri"));
```

Comment: Makoto and everyone else who responded,

  Thank you so much!  I can't believe how dumb I feel now.  Didn't even rationalize the fact that I was trying to mock the very class I wanted to test.  Thanks to all of your responses, I now have a valid test running.

Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Mockito only gives you *mock* objects. By default, calling any method on a mock does nothing at all. So when you call `getName` nothing happens and `getPathObj` is not called. You could try using a `spy` or `callRealMethod` but I've never use it because it seem to be not recommended (*code smells* ...) in mockito documentatin.

Answer (score 1):

The unit test verifies how an object interacts with its environment, not with itself.

Inyour case, the environmwent is `path`.

Assuming that you can inject a Path mock into your object, you need to do this:

```
JavaFileInput input = new JavaFileInput();
when(path.getFileName()).thenReturn("xxx.txt");
// inject path into input somehow
assertEquals("xxx.txt", input.getName());
```

If you cannot inject `path`, that's a code smell. Consider redesigning.